# How to comment on a question

Tags: support, comments

Maybe I'm just too blind to find the relevant button, but I just am not able to comment on a question, while I can perfectly well answer questions. Do I need more reputation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need 50 reputation. See the [What is reputation?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) section in the faq, and the [How does the comment system and comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-does-the-comment-system-and-comments-work/19757#19757) entry on the main meta

You can always comment on your own questions and answers, however, so you should see the link on this question:

[Screenshot of the add comment link http://mrozekma.com/so-unix-add-comment.png](http://mrozekma.com/so-unix-add-comment.png)

And you can comment on any answers to your questions, so you should see it just below this answer as well

```
|
|
v
```